# How can I place a new key value pair to the top of a hash?

Tags: ruby

I have some hash:

```
> my_hash = {b: "foo", c: "bar"}
```

I add a new key and it goes to the end:

```
> my_hash[:a] = "baz"
=> "baz"
> my_hash
=> {b: "foo", c: "bar", a: "baz"}
```

But I want it to go to the front:

```
> my_hash
=> {a: "baz", b: "foo", c: "bar"}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically hash elements' order is not important, but <del>who am I to judge your reasons</del> you might have valid reasons we don't know about. You can use `Hash#merge` for that:

```
> {a: "baz"}.merge(my_hash)
=> {:a=>"baz", :b=>"foo", :c=>"bar"}
> my_hash = {a: "baz"}.merge(my_hash)
=> {:a=>"baz", :b=>"foo", :c=>"bar"}
> my_hash
=> {:a=>"baz", :b=>"foo", :c=>"bar"}
```

Comment: Nice thanks! II'll use `merge!` to mutate the original. The order is just so "id" is at the top of the hash returned, just so the spec looks nice ha!

Comment: You'd need to assign new hash to an array to do that, right? You can't do `{a: "baz"}.merge!(my_hash)` I mean you can, but it does not differ from `merge`

Comment: If you already use ActiveSupport (Rails?) You might use `#reverse_merge!`: `my_hash.reverse_merge!(a: "baz")`

Comment: Grz, no you can't use `merge!`, but you could change `my_hash` in place by writing `my_hash.replace({a: "baz"}.merge(h))` btw, I have encountered a few situations where it was useful to make use of key ordering in a hash.

Comment: You mean `my_hash.replace({a: "baz"}.merge(my_hash))` right? I guess it's a personal preference, for me it's easier to parse `my_hash = {a: "baz"}.merge(my_hash) `. Care to make a blog post about the ordering? I'd love to read it.